# Floating Action Button is not getting INVISIBLE OR GONE

Tags: java, android

My Floating Action Buttons are not getting **INVISIBLE OR GONE**

When I click on add_btn it work fine it show animation and others buttons also get visible.
[image]

But when I click on add_btn second time animation work but buttons do not get INVISIVLE.

[image]

This is my java code for making floating action button visible and gone.

```
addFloatingBtn.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            if (!isFloatingActionBtnVisible){
                // Making Buttons Visible
                addVideoFloatingBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                addNotesFloatingBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                // Starting Animation
                addVideoFloatingBtn.startAnimation(fromBottom);
                addNotesFloatingBtn.startAnimation(fromBottom);
                addFloatingBtn.startAnimation(rotateOpen);
                isFloatingActionBtnVisible = true;
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Animation Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
                // Starting Animation
                addVideoFloatingBtn.startAnimation(toBottom);
                addNotesFloatingBtn.startAnimation(toBottom);
                addFloatingBtn.startAnimation(rotateClose);
                // Making Buttons Visible
                addVideoFloatingBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                addNotesFloatingBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                isFloatingActionBtnVisible = false;
            }
        });
```

This is xml code for three floating buttons.

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/add_floating_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
        android:tint="@color/white"
        android:background="@color/purple_500"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:focusable="true" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/add_video_floating_btn"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_video"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/add_floating_btn"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/add_floating_btn"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/add_floating_btn" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/add_notes_floating_btn"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_notes"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/add_video_floating_btn"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/add_video_floating_btn"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/add_video_floating_btn" />
```

- I want other floating action buttons get INVISIBLE when I click second time but they don't.

Comment: can you add animations as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [Beant Singh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19491703/beant-singh) for your suggestion. There was mistake in animation resource file.

This was my animation xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true">

    <translate android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="100%"
        android:duration="300"/>

    <scale
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toYScale="0.8"
        android:toXScale="0.8"/>

    <alpha
        android:duration="150"
        android:fromAlpha="0"
        android:toAlpha="100"/>

        <!-- Here is the mistake. I set fromAlpha="0" and toAlpha="100".
         Which was making floating action button visible even I set
         invisible from code. So I just fromAlpha="100" and toAlpha="0" and problem fixed.  -->
```